# Is it possible to check if an NSThread is blocked?

Tags: objective-c, locking, pthreads

I've always been interested in how to write the following code to use it for unit testing:

**Is it possible to extend NSThread with a method that would check if a particular thread is blocked?**

Right now I'am working with NSCondition: Xcode shows me the chain which is called by *-wait* to block the thread:

```
[NSCondition wait] 
pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003
_pthread_cond_wait
__psynch_cvwait
```

Besides checking the locks done by NSCondition, if it is even possible, I would highly appreciate method working also for any other blocking capabilities (dispatch semaphores, condition locks, sleeping threads and so on, ) - I have no idea about Objective-C internals, if maybe they could be catched by one method or each needs its own.

Here is a simple example of what I would like to achieve. The mysterious method is called **isBlocked**.

```
// Some test case
// ...

__block NSThread *thread;
NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition alloc] init];

dispatch_async(someQueue(), ^{
    thread = NSThread.currentThread; 

    [condition lock];
    [condition wait];
    [condition unlock];
});

while(1) {
    NSLog(@"Thread is blocked: %d", thread.isBlocked);
}
```

**Note:** I am not good at C and all this low-level POSIX stuff, so, please, be verbose.

**Note 2:** I am interested in solutions working for dispatch queues as well: if someone can show me how to test the fact that someQueue() is blocked by -[NSCondition wait] (not the fact that it is going to be blocked (fx hacking some code before -[condition wait] is run and the block is set), but the fact that **thread/queue is** blocked), I will accept this as an answer as much like I would do with working -[NSThread isBlocked] method.

**Note 3:** Suspecting bad news like "it is not possible", I claim that any ideas about catching the fact that -[condition wait] was run and the thread was set blocked (see Note 2) are appreciated and can be also accepted as an answer!

**UPDATE 1** in address to the nice answer by Richard J. Ross III. Unfortunately, his answer does not work in my original example, the version which is closer to my real work (though it does not differ much from the example I've initially provided - sorry that I didn't include it in the first edition of the question):

```
// Example

// Here I've bootstrapped Richard's isLocking categories for both NSThread and NSCondition
// ...

// somewhere in SenTesting test case...
__block NSThread *thread;
NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition alloc] init];
__block BOOL wePassedBlocking = NO;

dispatch_async(someQueue(), ^{
    thread = NSThread.currentThread; 

    [condition lock];
    [condition wait];
    [condition unlock];

    wePassedBlocking = YES; // (*) This line is occasionally never reached!
});

while(!thread.isWaitingOnCondition); // I want this loop to exit after the condition really locks someQueue() and _thread_ __.

// sleep(1);

[condition lock];
[condition broadcast]; // BUT SOMETIMES this line is called before -[condition wait] is called inside someQueue() so the entire test case becomes blocked!
[condition unlock];

while(!wePassedBlocking); // (*) And so this loop occasionally never ends!
```

If I uncomment **sleep(1)** test begins working very stable without any occasional locks!

This leads us to the problem, that Richard's category does set state exactly **one line before the actual blocking is done** meaning that **sometimes** test case's main thread catches this new state before we actually have *someQueue/thread* blocked because Richard's code **does not contain any synchronization mechanisms: @synchronized, NSLock or something like that**! I hope I am making a clear explanation of this tricky case. For anyone who has doubts about what I've posted here, I would say that I have been also experimenting with multiple queues and even more complex cases, and if needed I'm ready to provide more examples. Richard, thanks again for your effort, let's think more together, if you understand these my points!

**UPDATE 2**

I see the dead-end paradox: obviously, to really set the state of **waitingOnCondition** we need to wrap this state's change inside some synchronization closures, but the problem is that the closing one, unlocking the synchronization lock, should be called after -[condition wait], but it can't, because the thread is already blocked. Again, I hope I am describing it pretty clear.

Comment: Threads are not "locked". A thread can be *holding* a lock, or perhaps *waiting on* a lock, though -- is one of those what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, if I don't use the right terms. But I am sure my example does describe what I want, doesn't it? **-[condition wait]** "stops" thread until the moment when -[condition signal] will be called from some other thread - I want to catch the fact that condition was set to wait and thread has stopped rolling.

Comment: @Stanislaw Just write a category on NSThread that handles that, then.

Comment: @CodaFi, it is what I am asking here about ;) I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @CodaFi you make it sound like it's a trivial answer.. if it is, please share with us yours

Comment: The answer is: no, it's not possible to check if a thread is blocked.

Comment: @KenThomases, bad news! I did suspect this bad end! But could you please format your answer as an Answer in authoritative manner?

Comment: @KenThomases It may not be possible to check if it's blocked, but it would be trivial to add a bit of state to the thread

Comment: I dare say, most seasoned multithreading familiar developers don't use, don't need `isBlocked` kind of things. It might eventually backstab you in the end.

Comment: @9dan, I did asked this question more likely for educational purposes: I was just interested, if it was even possible to write such method (especially because of UPDATE 2 and still not knowing how multithreading is really done behind the scenes). I myself do mean to use this solution only in very rare specific 1 or 2 cases. I hope, that the fact that such question is asked, will not make folks to move in the wrong direction and so I hope these comments will also appeal to the people's mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go! It won't detect threads being waited on by anything other than `-[NSCondition wait]`, but it could easily be extended to detect other kinds of waiting.

It's probably not the best implementation out there, but it does in fact work, and will do what you need it to.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSThread(isLocking)

static int waiting_condition_key;

-(BOOL) isWaitingOnCondition {
    // here, we sleep for a microsecond (1 millionth of a second) so that the
    // other thread can catch up,  and actually call 'wait'. This time
    // interval is so small that you will never notice it in an actual
    // application, it's just here because of how multithreaded
    // applications work.    
    usleep(1);

    BOOL val = [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &waiting_condition_key) boolValue];

    // sleep before and after so it works on both edges
    usleep(1);

    return val;
}

-(void) setIsWaitingOnCondition:(BOOL) value {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &waiting_condition_key, @(value), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

@end

@implementation NSCondition(isLocking)

+(void) load {
    Method old = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(wait));
    Method new = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(_wait));

    method_exchangeImplementations(old, new);
}

-(void) _wait {
    // this is the replacement for the original wait method
    [[NSThread currentThread] setIsWaitingOnCondition:YES];

    // call  the original implementation, which now resides in the same name as this method
    [self _wait];

    [[NSThread currentThread] setIsWaitingOnCondition:NO];
}

@end

int main()
{
    __block NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition new];

    NSThread *otherThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:^{
        NSLog(@"Thread started");

        [condition lock];
        [condition wait];
        [condition unlock];

        NSLog(@"Thread ended");
    } selector:@selector(invoke) object:nil];
    [otherThread start];

    while (![otherThread isWaitingOnCondition]);

    [condition lock];
    [condition signal];
    [condition unlock];

    NSLog(@"%i", [otherThread isWaitingOnCondition]);
}
```

Output:

```
2013-03-20 10:43:01.422 TestProj[11354:1803] Thread started
2013-03-20 10:43:01.424 TestProj[11354:1803] Thread ended
2013-03-20 10:43:01.425 TestProj[11354:303] 0
```

Comment: Richard J. Ross III, I am interested to know what do you think about my updates 1 and 2 in the question I've just edited.

Comment: @Stanislaw I see your problem. I've added a lock to the... lock, so try that out and see if it works. If it doesn't, I'll make a custom mutex.

Comment: I've tried. It does not work without sleep(1) or even sleep(0.1). I am very intrigued to look at what "custom mutex is".

Comment: @Stanislaw what happens if you sleep for a microsecond with `usleep(1)`? And a custom mutex is a class that will properly lock in this scenario, and not rely on such wizardry as the runtime components.

Comment: usleep(1) seems to work! Is there any way to integrate it into your categories?

Comment: I will try to test it more, but somehow I think usleep(1) did the trick. Could you provide a detailed explanation of how this even could be possible? I will be very thankful!!!

Comment: @Stanislaw complete. check it out!

Comment: It does not work! Notice the difference: you sleep in the thread that is to be locked, and I did set your usleep(1) in the test case thread right after _while(!thread.isWaitingOnCondition);_ (instead of my sleep(1)) I am not sure what to do here )))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26556/discussion-between-stanislaw-and-richard-j-ross-iii)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dispatch_semaphore_t`

**PGFoo.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PGFoo : NSObject

- (void)longRunningAsynchronousMethod:(void (^)(NSInteger result))completion;

@end
```

**PGFoo.m**

```
#import "PGFoo.h"

@implementation PGFoo

- (void)longRunningAsynchronousMethod:(void (^)(NSInteger))completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(5);
        completion(1);
    });
}

@end
```

**Test Methods**

```
- (void)testThatFailsBecauseItIsImpatient {
    PGFoo *foo = [[PGFoo alloc] init];
    __block NSInteger theResult = 0;
    [foo longRunningAsynchronousMethod:^(NSInteger result) {
        theResult = result;
    }];

    STAssertEquals(theResult, 1, nil);
}

- (void)testThatPassesBecauseItIsPatient {
    PGFoo *foo = [[PGFoo alloc] init];
    __block NSInteger theResult = 0;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [foo longRunningAsynchronousMethod:^(NSInteger result) {
        theResult = result;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    STAssertEquals(theResult, 1, nil);
}
```

By using a `dispatch_semaphore_t` you can "track" whether a thread that is waiting on that semaphore is blocked. For every call of `dispatch_semaphore_wait` the semaphore's count is decremented and the thread waits until a call of `dispatch_semaphore_signal` is made, when `dispatch_semaphore_signal` is called the semaphore's count is incremented, if the count is incremented to a value greater than `-1` the thread continues.

This solution fails to answer your question about checking whether an `NSThread` is "blocked" but I think it provides what you are reaching for, assuming you're not reaching to check on `NSThread` instances that are maintained within an existing framework.

Comment: The problem with dispatch semaphores is that they use queues, which are not equivalent to threads.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII so wait a minute.. do you mean to say that all Grand Central Dispatchs' methods use queues.. which are fundamentally different than threads in objective-c?

Comment: @ChrisWagner, thanks for the answer - I've got what it is about, but really it is _not_ about what I'm asking in my question. I want a code that will make my example work _exactly_ (or at least close enough) in the form I've written (method -[NSThread isBlocked]). If you could adapt your idea closer to what I'm asking - it would be great!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I believe that it would be possible to adapt a code working for NSThread also for dispatch queues, if such code itself could be created. Though I see, it is a very tricky one, if not even impossible.

Comment: @abbood that is correct. A single thread can actually have multiple queues running on it, and a single queue is *almost* equivalent to a while loop spawning blocks. Not entirely, though.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Oh I see. Prolly that's why GCD is not a good choice for real-time.. I quote from this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12454761/766570) "[GCD] is not acceptable for realtime audio. it uses pools and queues, and the realtime dependent work you submit to it can sit in the queue for a long time, and that is beyond your control. best to dedicate your work to a realtime high priority thread, and make the work on that thread very simple and very fast."

Comment: @abbood that is similar to what I've read too. I've never needed that level of control in my apps so I have been heavily reliant on GCD and NSOperation. The simplicity/abstraction of GCD over "real threads" is really nice when it works for your requirements.

Comment: @ChrisWagner and `NSOperation` is simply a wrapper around `GCD` right? so using `NSOperation` doesn't add any significant cost over `GCD` right?

Comment: @abbood Yes, Apple suggests always using the highest level API if possible, and NSOperation was rewritten to use GCD when GCD came out (iOS 4?). There are always limitations the higher you go, so it makes sense to use GCD directly at times.